# Explain the code snippet in Django

Tags: python, django, blogs, code-snippets, zinnia

I am pretty new to Django. I am fiddling with zinnia to customize it and setting it up with my own theme/template etc. The main `content` displayed in the default template is following:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
  {% include object.content_template with object_content=object.html_preview continue_reading=1 %}
{% empty %}
```

I understand that `include` includes the template inside a page. But what I cannot comprehend is: how do I find the relevant template being rendered? What is `content_template`? Please help me in understanding this snippet.

Comment: Would really help if those voting to close can at least comment and specify the reason. I would avoid such questions if I know the reason.

Comment: Don't worry about it, someone just want the vote down badge.

Comment: `content_template` is an attribute of `object`, which is an element of `object_list`. Look in your view to see what `object_list`, and then in the models file to find out what `object` is and what attributes it has.

Comment: @Evert Trying this. Thanks for direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template name (`content_template`) is being fetched from the database. It is a property of the model [`ContentTemplateEntry`](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/develop/zinnia/models_bases/entry.py#L537) and defaults to `zinnia/_entry_detail.html`.